# how to write to .mat file matlab

Tags: string, file, matlab

I have a couple of .mat files in my folder. I want to write to each of them a couple of variables, strings, specified by myself during execution of this program. How can I write from matlab and save these strings to .mat ?

Comment: Do it with `load` and `save`. [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append the .mat files using the `-append` flag when saving.  If the variable name you are trying to append to the file already exists in the file, it will overwritten with this command.

Ex.

```
>> save <your .mat filename> <your variables> -append
```

Comment: thanks, it is clear but I cannot use in this expression variable containig name. how to do it?
name = 'file.mat'
save name  a b -append;

Comment: I am not sure I understand your problem.  To save all variables that are currently in your workspace, you can leave the `<your variables>` section empty.  If your existing filename is "file.mat", then to add new data, say a variable "b", you can simply `>> save file b -append`

Comment: yes, what I tried to ask is a stupid question, but help tells me nothing about it and I cannot fix: when into **<your .mat filename>** I put **file.mat** it goes. but when I declare **name = 'file.mat'** and then put there **name**, it doesn't. With name is more flexible, because can be **name(i)** assigned, so I need it this way.

Comment: I see.  Something like this:  `>> name=file.mat`  So, to save, you would do `>> save(name, 'variable 1', 'variable 2')`  Or, if your filename already exists and you want to append it, do `>> save(name, 'variable 1', '-append')`.  Does this help?

Comment: thank you very much! I was trying various combinations, weird this didn't go, maybe I did some spelling mistake. problem solved!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the command save with "-append" parameter

save matfile -append

Check the details at http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f10-61206.html