# How to create a .mat file in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have 25 images in a folder and I want to make a **.mat** file for a road-sign recognition system.

What are the steps for making a .mat file in Matlab?

Comment: Have you looked at [`save`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html)?

Comment: I looked at the save command but I don't understand how to code all my images. Also I have a question in at the structure of matfile command what is meant the first term?

Comment: What's the largest file size of an image?

Comment: All my images have 273x273 size

Comment: I use [`save`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) a lot but have never used for images. I'm going to post an answer. If it doesn't work for your images feel free to comment on it and let me know and I'll delete and look into alternatives.

Comment: Ok! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

There may be a better approach for images but here is what I know. If you want to control what goes into the **.mat** file you can specify what variables in your workspace will be saved using the [`save`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) command.

```
% MATLAB R2017a
X = rand(273,273);
Y = rand(273,273);
Z = rand(273,273);

save FileName X Y Z
```

This creates a file **FileName.mat**.
You can access the contents using the [`load`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html) command.

```
clear
load FileName
```

To save everything in the workspace to a **.mat** file, use the [`save`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) command without specifying the variables to save (MATLAB will then save them all).

```
W = rand(273,273);
save FileName
```

See the linked documentation for more options and examples.

This requires you to loop through the images in the folder. A direct approach to this is directly loading the images using a loop over `[filepath 'image' num2str(j) '.jpg']` with index `j` where `filepath = 'C:\Users\user1\Folder\ImageFolder\'`. This uses string concatenation and the [`num2str`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html) command.

If you need to change your current directory within the script,the [`cd`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cd.html) function is useful.

---

**Related Posts:**
[store multi images in mat file using matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44440630/8239061)
[how to write to .mat file matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11904031/8239061)

Comment: I will test and i will be back with the results. Thank you very much!